# Express: Embed document in the existing document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, one-to-many

I am developing an application in `Express`, `Node` and `Mongo` being the database. I have a collection `users`, and `user` can have mutiple `registered-IDs`. It like a `one-to-many` relationship. I m trying to embed a `document` in the user collection like this:

```
post(function (req, res, next) {
    var pid=req.body.pid;
    var sid=req.body.sid;
    var rfname=req.body.rfname;
    var des=req.body.des;
    var brand=req.body.brand;
    var model=req.body.model;
    var serial=req.body.serial;
    var location=req.body.location;

    var arr={pid: 'pid', sid: 'sid', rfname: 'rfname' ,des: 'des', brand: 'brand', model: 'model' ,serial: 'serial', location: 'location'};

    mongoose.model('User').findOne({'pemail': req.session.email}, function (err, user){
        if(err){

        } else {
            user.registeredId = arr;

            user.save(function(err){
                if(err){

                } else {
                    res.render('user/register', {'success': 'dfhlaksdhfh'});
                }
            })
        }
    });
}
```

My user schema is like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
  email: String,
  password: String,
  fname: String,
  lname: String,
  plang: String,
  slang: String,
  country: String,
  state: String,
  city: String,
  postalcode: String,
  address1: String,
  address2: String,
  pemail: String,
  semail: String,
  age: String,
  gender: String,
  pphone: String,
  sphone: String,
  q1: String,
  a1: String,
  q2: String,
  a2: String,
  cfname: String,
  clname: String,
  cemail: String
});
mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Guide me, what am i doing wrong, because it does not embed document in the existing document. Do I need to define that in schema, if so, then how?

Comment: There is no defined field `registeredId` in your schema, which is why the assignment is rejected. You also really want an `array` instead if you want "one-to-many" and of course `.push()` to that defined array in the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schema definition, the field `registeredId` is not defined and by default through the **[strict option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict)**, Mongoose ensures that values passed to your model constructor that were not specified in our schema do not get saved to the db, hence it is not creating the modified document.

You can either explicitly define the field in your schema or set the strict option to false in your schema definition:

```
// set to false..
var userSchema = new Schema({..}, { strict: false });
```

and then implement one of the **[`findAndModify()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)** methods like **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)** to update your user document by pushing the new object to the new array field `registeredId`. So you could re-write your post function as:

```
post(function (req, res, next) {
    var User = mongoose.model('User'),
        pid=req.body.pid,
        sid=req.body.sid,
        rfname=req.body.rfname,
        des=req.body.des,
        brand=req.body.brand,
        model=req.body.model,
        serial=req.body.serial,
        location=req.body.location, 
        arr = {
            'pid': pid, 
            'sid': sid, 
            'rfname': rfname,
            'des': des, 
            'brand': brand, 
            'model': model,
            'serial': serial, 
            'location': location
        },
        condition = { 'pemail': req.session.email },
        update = {
            "$push": { 'registeredId': arr }
        };

    User.findOneAndUpdate(
        condition,
        update,
        function (err, doc){
            if(err){} 
            else {
                // doc contains the modified document
                res.render('user/register', {'success': 'dfhlaksdhfh'});
            }
        }
    );
});
```